# How to write a secure websocket server in java desktop application

Tags: java, websocket, server, desktop-application, embedded-jetty

I have a Java Desktop Application, and this application starts a secure websocket server, written in Java. Right now it is using a self-signed certificate which requires the web browser user to manually accept the self-signed certificate to be able to start a client connection to the same websocket server.

I have a SSL certificate for a domain like "mydomain.com", and I'd like to use that SSL certificate to start the Java Desktop Application's secure websocket. Of course the computer will have to point that domain to the local machine, so I added `127.0.0.1   mydomain.com` to my HOSTS file (I'm in Windows). Even so, it is not working.

So the question is:

> Is it possible to create a Secure Websocket Server from this Java
>   Desktop Application, so that if my local browser tries to access
>   wss://mydomain.com/appservices it accepts the certificate as usual
>   (given the HOSTS file modification) ?, If this is possible, How can I
>   do that given the following example code?

**Additional info and examples of current code**

Here is the code that starts the secure websocket server in my Java Desktop App:

```
package com.mydomain.desktopclient.websockets.server;

import com.mydomain.desktopclient.resources.ResourceLoader;
import com.mydomain.desktopclient.websockets.server.endpoint.RequestServerEndpoint;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer;
import java.net.URL;

public class SecureWebSocketServer {

    Server server = null;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server = new Server();
        int httpsPort = 443;

        URL keystore = ResourceLoader.getLocalResourceURL("/resources/misc/keystore/keystore.jks");
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystore.toExternalForm());
        sslContextFactory.setCertAlias("mydomain.com.key");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("keystorepass");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("keymanagerpass");
        sslContextFactory.addExcludeProtocols("SSLv3");
        sslContextFactory.addExcludeCipherSuites(".*_GCM_.*");

        HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpsConf.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
        httpsConf.setSecureScheme("https");
        httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

        ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
        httpsConnector.setHost("mydomain.com");
        httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);
        server.addConnector(httpsConnector);

        HandlerList baseHandlers = new HandlerList();
        server.setHandler(baseHandlers);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        // context.setVirtualHosts(new String[] {"mydomain.com"});
        context.setContextPath("/");

        baseHandlers.addHandler(context);

        // Add WebSocket
        ServerContainer jsrContainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);
        jsrContainer.setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        jsrContainer.addEndpoint(RequestServerEndpoint.class);

        Handler handler = new DefaultHandler();
        baseHandlers.addHandler(handler);

        server.setDumpAfterStart(true);
        server.setDumpBeforeStop(true);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        if( server != null ){
            server.stop();
            server = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code uses `jetty-all-9.3.1.v20150714-uber.jar` as websocket library.

The class `com.mydomain.desktopclient.resources.ResourceLoader` is a simple class to find and return files as resources from the app's jar file.

Here is the RequestServerEndpoint if needed:

```
package com.mydomain.desktopclient.websockets.server.endpoint;

import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/appservices")
public class RequestServerEndpoint {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestServerEndpoint.class.getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        logger.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String incommingMessage, Session session) {
        logger.info("Received Message: \n\n" + incommingMessage);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }
}
```

Comment: The mentioned jetty library can be obtained here: [https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/9.3.1.v20150714/]

Comment: Did you got any solution? I have the same question, but I have another problem too: My websocket server is disconnected after some minutes

Comment: I'm still unsure if the local secure websocket server solution is possible, i had to use another approach: A websocket bridge. The browser connects to a standard secure websocket hosted in a web server on the Internet, and the desktop application does the same. The communication between the browser and the desktop client can be achieved by starting the desktop app using CUSTOM PROTOCOL (like myapp://parameters_here). This should start and pass parameters to the desktop app so that it completes the bridge with the browser through the server.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I got a solution using steganography, and my server run as a window services, so, i don't need custom protocols. The steganography way is slow, around 500ms plus the older time it took. But it works.